Is naive mean estimator uniformly worse than HT (IPW) or Hajek estimators in survey sampling? If not, why is it less discussed in the literature?
Consider a toy example: we are interested in the average height of $n$ students $\bar{\tau}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_i$, but for some reason, we can only access a random subset $S$ of it. Every student will be chosen (independently) with probability $\pi_i$. If student $i$ is chosen, we say $i\in S$. Now observing $S$, $\{\tau_i:i\in S\}$ and $\{\pi_i\}_{i=1}^n$, we have many ways to estimate $\tau$.
naive mean estimator
$$\hat{\tau}_{\text{naive}}=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{i\in S}\tau_i=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_iI(i\in S)}{\sum_{i=1}^nI(i\in S)}.$$
HT (IPW) estimator
$$\hat{\tau}_{\text{ht}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\tau_iI(i\in S)}{\pi_i}.$$
Hajek (standardized IPW) estimator
$$\hat{\tau}_{\text{haj}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\tau_iI(i\in S)}{\pi_i}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{I(i\in S)}{\pi_i}}.$$
There are many discussions about HT and Hajek estimators in literature, while rare about "naive mean" estimator. I did some simulation and found that $\hat{\tau}_{\text{naive}}$ is not bad (even better than others) under many scnarios, so my question is: is there any theoretical guarantee on it?  (Something like its bias may be negligible under some conditions, etc.) Thanks a lot!
Appendix: there are my empirical results and R codes.
      naive    ht   haj
bias2 0.061 0.000 0.003
var   0.176 0.735 0.688
mse   0.237 0.735 0.691


rm(list=ls());gc()
set.seed(1)
n = 100
tau = rnorm(n,0,5)
tau.bar = mean(tau)
pi = runif(n,0,1)
nruns = 1000
res.df = data.frame(naive=rep(0,nruns),
                    ht=rep(0,nruns),
                    haj=rep(0,nruns))
for(nrun in 1:nruns) {
  S = rbinom(n,1,pi)
  S.ind = (1:n)[as.logical(S)]
  res.df$naive[nrun] = mean(tau[S.ind])
  res.df$ht[nrun] = mean(tau*S/pi)
  res.df$haj[nrun] = mean(tau*S/pi)/mean(S/pi)
}

boxplot(res.df)
abline(a=tau.bar,b=0,col='red')
res.bias2 = (apply(res.df,2,mean)-tau.bar)^2
res.var = apply(res.df,2,var)
res.mse = res.bias2 + res.var
plot(1:3,res.mse,ylim=c(0,1))
lines(1:3,res.var,col='red')
lines(1:3,res.bias2,col='blue')


I realize they are all 'linear' estimators about $\tau_i$, maybe there have been some unified framework to discuss that?

Maybe we can analyse it through WLS regression?

Many scenarios? I suppose if $\pi_i$ is independent of $\tau_i$  or if you use bernouli variables so the biases cancel out maybe the bias is manageable, but in realistic situations, I don't think you'd ever go for the naive estimator.
